# CoreData predicate using relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

I have two entities - `Quotes` and `Customers`. One customer can have many quotes. The relationships are `quotes` and `customers`.

I want to get a quote object based on the customer name and email address, sorted by date but I'm stuck trying to format the predicate...

```
func getMostRecentQuote(name: String, email: String) -> Quotes? {
   var predicateList = [NSPredicate]()
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Quotes")
   let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", name)
   let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "email CONTAINS[c] %@", email)
   let orCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
   predicateList.append(orCompoundPredicate)

   fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: predicateList)
   fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
```

Comment: Is the `customers` relationship to-one, or to-many?

Comment: One customer can have many quotes so...to many? (A quote can only have one customer.) Thanks!

Comment: In that case, see @vadian’s answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a to-one relationship from `Quotes` to `Customers`, if not,  establish one and name the property `customer`

Then use this single predicate

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "customer.name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR customer.email CONTAINS[c] %@", name, email)
```

If you want to filter the full string caseinsensitive `CONTAINS` is actually the wrong operator, better use `LIKE`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "customer.name LIKE[c] %@ OR customer.email LIKE[c] %@", name, email)
```

Note: Please name entities in singular form, semantically your method is going to return one *Quote*, not one *Quotes*

Comment: I wondered about pluralizing entity names. Some methods do return many quotes, but often, as in this case, it's singular. Well, hopefully singular. Thank you!

Comment: Multiple quotes are an array of Quote instances (`[Quote]`)

Comment: Ohhhhh...stupid CloudKit tutorial. I changed all of my entities to match my RecordTypes.